# Node/Express API when getting mutlipel requests data gets mixed up and incorrect results occur

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, microsoft-graph-api

I have a nodejs/express backend api that when I get hundreds of requests within seconds I start to get mixed results where data is crossed between requests and leads to unexpected and incorrected results. Can someone point me to where I am incorrectly defining variables that when I get one of the await functions it causes the other variables to be overwritten with the next requests data and causing my issues.

```
router.post('/autoscan3', async(req,res,next) => {

  let authrule = "autoscan"

  console.log(req.body.companyDomain  + "   " + req.body.user + " for folder: " + req.body.folderid)


  let totalscans = 0;

  let client = await getDB();
  let authorizationResults = await checkAuthorization(client, req.body.companyDomain);

  const featureSet = authorizationResults.features;
  let company = authorizationResults.company;
  const clientid = authorizationResults.client_id;
  const clientsecret = authorizationResults.secret;

  let tenantid = await getTenantID(req.body.companyDomain, client);

  let token = await msgraphservices.getClientCredentialsAccessToken(tenantid, clientid, clientsecret)
  let scanResults = []
  let folderscans = 0;
  try{
    for(let a = 0; a < req.body.messages.length; a++){
      let senderAddress = req.body.messages[a].senderAddress;
      let emailBody = req.body.messages[a].emailBody;
      let messageid = req.body.messages[a].messageid;
      let receivedDateTime = req.body.messages[a].receivedDateTime;
      let user = req.body.messages[a].recieverAddress;
      let subject = req.body.messages[a].subject;
      let attachments = req.body.messages[a].attachments;
      let links = req.body.messages[a].emailBodyLinks;
      let headers = req.body.messages[a].headers
      let knownaddress
      if (senderAddress.includes(req.body.companyDomain)) {
        knownaddress = 10
      } else {
        knownaddress = await searchForSender(client, senderAddress, req.body.user, token, "");}

      let assessmentResults = await assessment(
            messageid,
            emailBody,
            senderAddress,
            user,
            subject,
            receivedDateTime,
            company,
            attachments,
            links,
            req.body.companyDomain,
            client,
            headers,
            knownaddress,
            featureSet,
            authrule
          )
      console.log('adding to folderscans')
      folderscans++
      try {
        await msgraphservices.updateUserCategory2(messageid, req.body.user, req.body.folderid, assessmentResults.riskFactor,token)
      }
      catch(e) {
        console.log(`error on category tag for ${messageid} with user ${req.body.user}`);
        console.log(e);
        }
    }
      console.log(`folder scans ${folderscans}`);
      totalscans = totalscans + folderscans
    return res.status(200).json({status:"success", totalscans:totalscans});
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(`error while trying to loop for user ${req.body.user}`)
    console.log(e)
    logapierror(e.stack, req.body.user, req.body)
    return res.status(200).json({status:'error', totalscans:totalscans, error:e});
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's very likely `let client = await getDB();`

If multiple requests use the same snapshot of the database but don't know about each other, it's very likely that they're overwriting each other's data.

Comment: Unfortunately they all really only update the DB but don't read from it, the issue is more with the messageid etc. Those fields when they get to the last update category function are no longer the correct message id for the user and mailfolder.